# Can't pass parameters to routes between functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have two functonal components in separate folders/files like this

**the first one:**

```
export const Inscription = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    // ...    
    function _InscDrog(apiName) {
        InscDrog(apiName).then(data => {
            setResp(data);
            setIsLoading(false);
            if (data.success) {
                navigation.push("Mdp", { phone: '0600000000', }) // this is how I pass params
            } else {
                console.log('success false', JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        })
    }
    //...
    return (
        <View
            style={[Styles.container, { backgroundColor: theme.mainColor }]}>
            {/* ... */}
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => _InscDrog('Inscription.php',)}
                style={Styles.buttonLogin}>
                <Text style={Styles.buttonLoginTitle}>Check</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {/* ... */}
        </View>
    );
};
```

**The second one:** where I have to get the params

```
export const Mdp = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    // ...    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(route), '>> props');
    //{"key":"Mdp-Ju0lgXVp1JjhleQ3PuTbS","name":"Mdp","params":{}} >> props

    //...
    return (
        <View
            style={[Styles.container, { backgroundColor: theme.mainColor }]}>
            {/* ... */}
        </View>
    );
};
```

And as you can see if I log `route` the `params` object is empty I don't know if I can't pass the params or I can't read theme.

Comment: try `navigation.push({ pathname: 'Mdp', state: { { phone: '0600000000',  }})`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
   ...
   navigation.dispatch(StackActions.push("Mdp", { phone: '0600000000', }))
```

[source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#push)

Comment: how can I get the params in the other component ? route.params is still empty !

Comment: are you sure if you not just getting undefined at initial render? not after the api comes back?